# Timestamp issue copying parquet files from Hive to Vertica

Tags: hive, parquet, vertica, microfocus

We have an external hive table with Parquet files backed in the S3 location as shown below.
[image]

Our EMR runs in PDT/PST timezone. We copy this data from hive to vertica using the vertica copy command. Our Vertica cluster is also in PDT/PST.

On 3rd Nov (time changed to PST) when the EMR ran the copy command for the above data, the timestamp lags by an hour in vertica  as shown below

[image]

Datatype used in hive and vertica for date field is "timestamp".

Can anyone please explain why this issue is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the suspicion that Hive, with `TIMESTAMP`, implies `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`. I know for a fact that Vertica treats the two as two distinct data types.

Worth trying to investigate down that path ...